# Can't figure out why the native Promise variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a large JavaScript library that I've compressed with Google's closure compiler.

I've wrapped my compressed code in an anonymous function so that I don't get name collisions, which is included as an external file like this

```
// My external JS file
(function(){
    // Closure compiler compressed code
})();
```

But because of this my code keeps throwing an error that `Promise` is undefined. But the strange thing is is that it's available in the scope of the main page. So if I go to the very top of the call stack and type `Promise` in the console it gives me back the function. I've checked that it's not being overritten anywhere.

I can't think of anything else that could cause it to be undefined, I'm stuck.

**How can the anonymous function cause the `Promise` variable to be undefined?**

I've uploaded a screen cast [here](https://youtu.be/1stojenyeUo) demonstrating my issue, it's a bit laggy with the screen cast software running.

EDIT: Promise is an in-built native variable in the current version of chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what was going on was hoisting. Somewhere in my code there was something along these lines

```
// This condition was never being met as it contained code to check if I'm
// in a node.js environment.
if (thisConditionIsNotTrue){
    // But because there's no 'var' before Promise it's being hoisted and 
    // setting my global Promise variable to undefined. Even though if the
    // require statement was actually run it would throw an error as it
    // doesn't exist in the browser.
    Promise = require("node-promise").Sj;
}
```